# How to customise the menu on a LG G Watch

Tags: android-wear

I recently received an LG G Watch. I've been playing around with it and find it a very difficult to understand device. E.g. I want to customize the menu that you bring up by tapping the screen and then sliding up. A lot of the options in there simply don't apply to me and I want them removed.

How to I customize the LG G Watch menu?

Answer (score 1):

From my  [reading of the LG G Watch User manual pdf](http://tool.xcdn.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=CT014306432109876543213/RDL-1407-00176_LG-W100_UK4_UG_Web_V1.0_140709.pdf/RDL-1407-00176_LG-W100_UK4_UG_Web_V1.0_140709.pdf)  there are 2 sets of data that can be brought up from a 'Swipe Up' action.

1) Google Now. This can be customised through the 'Wand' Icon in Google now, and swiping away cards will often give the prompt "Do you wish to continue to receive updates about < whatever >? I doubt this is what you are referring to.

2) The actual settings/options. There is no mention here or anywhere else as to customising these options. I can't imagine you'd be allowed (or want to) remove something like "Pairing" or "Display" options for obvious reasons, they seem to apply the same rationale to all options, as is standard on all Android devices.

If, on the off chance, you are referring to the app drawer, then you would have to uninstall the app from your phone first as the Android Wear app synchs all compatible apps.

Finally the only other thing I can think of is Notifications you don't want. In this case:

> - On your **phone** open the Android Wear app.
> - Touch the Settings Icon
> - Touch **Mute Notifications**
> - Click the + Icon
> - Choose what app(s) you want to mute.

Comment: Thanks for that. Not really sure if this helps me though, I simply do not comprehend the UI of this thing at all. I think the G Watch goes onto eBay soon..

Comment: Well, I mistakenly linked to the PDF on my C: drive, which I haven't done since the 90s. I've updated it now, maybe read it and see if it helps. These watches are new technology, and they may get Firmware updates that make things easier going forward.

Comment: Also I'd just add, why not watch some videos about the device on YouTube? Look at people use it, and see if it helps. I found this great when I first got into smart phones etc. It's not the most thrilling viewing, but it helps!

Comment: I've tried. I can only find unboxing and very very basic videos, nothing that goes indepth. If you know any good videos, please let me know.